# Expectation of the first order statistic conditional on the value of the second one.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

Let $_{(1)},\ldots,_{()}$ be the order statistics of a set of $$ independent uniform [0,1] random variables.

1. Find the conditional expectation of $_{(1)}$ given that $_{(2)}=x_2~$, i.e. $~\mathbb{E}(_{(1)}|_{(2)}=x_2)$
2. Find the conditional expectation of $_{(2)}$ given that $_{(1)}=x_1~$, i.e. $~\mathbb{E}(_{(2)}|_{(1)}=x_1)$

That's what I got for now, but I'm not sure is my result correct.

I just found the conditional pfds $f_{X_1|X_2}$ and $f_{X_2| X_1}$ using the [join distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution) $f_{X_1,X_2}$

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=n!\frac{x_1^{1-1}}{(1-1)!}\frac{(x_2-x_1)^{2-1-1}}{(2-1-1)!}\frac{(1-x_2)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} = n(n-1)(1-x_2)^{n-2}$$

and [pdfs of order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$
$$f_{X_1}(x_1) = \frac{n!}{(1-1)!(n-1)!}x_1^{1-1}(1-x_1)^{n-1} = n(1-x_1)^{n-1}$$
$$f_{X_2}(x_2) = \frac{n!}{(2-1)!(n-2)!}x_2^{2-1}(1-x_2)^{n-2} = n(n-1)x_2(1-x_2)^{n-2}$$

Hence,
$$f_{X_1|X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)}{f_{X_2}(x_2)} = \frac{n(n-1)(1-x_2)^{n-2}}{n(n-1)x_2(1-x_2)^{n-2}} = \frac{1}{x_2}$$
$$f_{X_2|X_1}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)}{f_{X_1}(x_1)} = \frac{n(n-1)(1-x_2)^{n-2}}{n(1-x_1)^{n-1}} = (n-1)\frac{(1-x_2)^{n-2}}{(1-x_1)^{n-1}}$$

And used them to find conditional expectations.

$$\mathbb{E}(X_1|x_2) = \int\limits_0^{x_2} x_1 f_{X_1|X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1 = \int\limits_0^{x_2} \frac{x_1}{x_2}dx_1 = \frac{x_2}{2}$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X_2|x_1) = \int\limits_{x_1}^1 x_2 f_{X_2|X_1}(x_1,x_2)dx_2 = \int\limits_{x_1}^1 x_2 (n-1)\frac{(1-x_2)^{n-2}}{(1-x_1)^{n-1}}dx_2 = \frac{1+(n-1)x_1}{n}$$

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing about something called $f_{x_1,x_2}(x_1,x_2),$ but instead about $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2).$ (Capital) $X_1,X_2$ are random variables; lowre case $x_1,x_2$ are arguments to the density, which could be any numbers.

Comment: @Michael fair point. I changed it. Do you see any other problems with my solution?

Comment: I haven't checked everything, but your bottom-line answers are correct.

Comment: Great. Thank you.